# How to minimize the sum of all nodes in a tree?

Tags: algorithm, tree

Given a tree with 'n' nodes and 'n-1' edges.

We are also given a set of  'n-1'  weights .

We have to assign each weight to exactly one of the edges.

We have to assign it in a way such that the sum of all nodes in a tree is minimized.

Value of a node = maximum weight of all of its adjacent edges.

Example:- 
Edges:- (1--2),
(2--3)

Weights:-{1,2}

Solution : - Assigning weight '2' to edge '1--2' and weight '1' to edge '2--3' , we get,

value of node '1' : - 2

value of node '2' : - 2

value of node '3' : - 1

Total minimum sum possible : - (2+2+1)=5 .

How to approach ?

Comment: Did you try anything to solve this? If yes then please put the code here and update question with exact issue which you are facing.

Comment: I did not get anything to try for